# Make multidimensional array with php and pdo

Tags: php, arrays, database, pdo

i want to edit a script i found online. is has an hardcoded array like this.

```
$servers = array(
    'Google Web Search' => array(
        'ip' => '',
        'port' => 80,
        'info' => 'Hosted by The Cloud',
        'purpose' => 'Web Search'
    ),
    'Example Down Host' => array(
        'ip' => 'example.com',
        'port' => 8091,
        'info' => 'ShittyWebHost3',
        'purpose' => 'No purpose'
    )
);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["Google Web Search"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ip"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["port"]=>
    int(80)
    ["info"]=>
    string(19) "Hosted by The Cloud"
    ["purpose"]=>
    string(10) "Web Search"
  }
  ["Example Down Host"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ip"]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
    ["port"]=>
    int(8091)
    ["info"]=>
    string(14) "ShittyWebHost3"
    ["purpose"]=>
    string(10) "No purpose"
  }
}
```

I put this data in a database and want to make the same array but i dont seem to get it working

This is the code i added to make an array:

```
$query ="SELECT name, ip, port, hosting FROM sites";
$select = $conn->prepare($query);
$select->execute(array());
$testing = array();
while($rs = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $testing[] = array($rs['name'] => array('ip'=> $rs['ip'], 'port'=> $rs['port'], 'hosting'=> $rs['hosting']));
}
```

The result from this is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Google Web Search"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["ip"]=>
      string(10) "google.com"
      ["port"]=>
      string(2) "80"
      ["hosting"]=>
      string(19) "Hosted by The Cloud"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Example Down Host"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["ip"]=>
      string(11) "example.com"
      ["port"]=>
      string(2) "09"
      ["hosting"]=>
      string(14) "ShittyWebHost3"
    }
  }
}
```

is there a way to make the bottom array the same as the top array, i dont want to edit the whole script, this seems easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you assign a value to an array you use the syntax `$arr[key] = $value`. If you omit the key during the assignment, `$value` will be assigned to the next available integer key of the array, starting from 0.
This is an example of how it works:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 'one';//Empty, so insert at 0 [0=>'one']
$arr[] = 'two';//Last element at 0, so use 1 [0=>'one',1=>'two']
$arr[6]= 'three';//Key is used, so use key [0=>'one',1=>'two',6=>'three']
$arr[] = 'four';//Max used integer key is 6, so use 7
print_r($arr);//[0=>'one',1=>'two',6=>'three',7=>'four']
```

So, when in your code you are using

```
$testing[] = array(
    $rs['name'] => array(
        'ip'=> $rs['ip'], 
        'port'=> $rs['port'], 
        'hosting'=> $rs['hosting']
    )
);
```

You are assigning the newly created array to the positions 0,1,2,..N.

To avoid this, just specify the key explicitly, using the value you really want, like

```
$testing['name'] => array(
    'ip'=> $rs['ip'], 
    'port'=> $rs['port'], 
    'hosting'=> $rs['hosting']
);
```

You can read more about arrays in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

**Side note**
If you don't mind having an extra column in the generated arrays, you can rewrite entirely your code this way:

```
$query ="SELECT name, ip, port, hosting FROM sites";
$results = $conn->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$testing = array_column($results,null,'name');
```

It's slightly slower, but very handy in my opinion, `PDOStatement::fetchAll` retrieves all the data at once and `array_column` using `null` as second parameter does reindex the array with the wanted column as key.

- [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
- [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Thanks so much! i have used the database solution, it seems easier and less code!

Comment: Why downvote? Not to complain, just to enhance the answer, if possible...

Answer (score 0):

You are appending a new integer indexed element with `[]` and then adding 2 nested arrays.  Instead, add the name as the key:

```
 $testing[$rs['name']] = array('ip'=> $rs['ip'],
                               'port'=> $rs['port'],
                               'hosting'=> $rs['hosting']);
```

Since you specify the columns in the query and they are the same as the array keys, then just this:

```
 $testing[$rs['name']] = $rs;
```